# How do i send multiple Integers to a new activity?

Tags: android, string, android-activity, int

I have a way that I know is not the best way of sending them over rite now but I'm sending them as strings and converting them to an Int on the reciver side, the problem is when I do the conversion it crashes on my phone. This is what I have on my sender side:

```
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayTracker.class);
    // hourly wage send
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourly_wage);
    String message1 = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_1, message1);
    // ot wage send
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ot_wage);
    String message2 = editText1.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_2, message2);
    // hours per day send
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hours_day);
    String message3 = editText2.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_3, message3);
    // start new activity
    startActivity(intent);
```

And this is what is on my reciving side:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_tracker);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Receive messages from options page
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(Options.MESSAGE_1);
    String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(Options.MESSAGE_2);
    String message3 = intent.getStringExtra(Options.MESSAGE_3);
    // convert string to integer
    int HW = Integer.valueOf(message1);
    int OTW = Integer.valueOf(message2);
    int HPD = Integer.valueOf(message3);
```

Ive tested everything and its the conversion that is causing the app to crash, i was hoping somebody could help me make it not crash or give me a whole new way sending an int to my second activity insted of sending a string and converting it.
Thank you!

=======================================================================

Here is my new code with all your help!

Sending:

```
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayTracker.class);
    // Gather text from text boxes
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourly_wage);
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ot_wage);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hours_day);
    //Create String from text
    String message1 = editText.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText1.getText().toString();
    String message3 = editText2.getText().toString();
    //Convert String to Int
    int HW = 0, OTW = 0, HPD = 0;
    try{
        HW = Integer.valueOf(message1);
        OTW = Integer.valueOf(message2);
        HPD = Integer.valueOf(message3);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        //do something else here
        //for e.g. initializing default values to your int variables
    }
    // Send Integers to PayTracker.java
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_HW, HW);
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_OTW, OTW);
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_HPD, HPD);
    // start new activity
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Receiving side:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_tracker);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Receive messages from options page
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int HW = intent.getIntExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HW, 0);
    int OTW = intent.getIntExtra(Options.MESSAGE_OTW, 0);
    int HPD = intent.getIntExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HPD, 0);
    // set textview
    TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.yourpay);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(HW));
}
```

Comment: It just says that the app "payme" (thats the temp name of my app) has stopped working

Comment: Try a Log.i("user1552475","-->"+message1+"<--") in both your classes and check the log.

Comment: `Integers` do not need to be added as `Strings`. By packing them into your `Intent` as `Integers`, you should be able to avoid the conversion issue.

Comment: @Vinoth kind of, i ran into another issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass `Integers` as `Strings` to be converted back in the receiving `Activity`. `Intents` can hold `Integers` as well as `Strings`.

Simply add your data like you normally would:

```
int foo = 5;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, bar.class);
intent.putExtra("foobar", foo);
```

And then retrieve your `int` from the intent in the receiving `Activity` as follows.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int foo = intent.getIntExtra("foobar", 0);
```

`Intents` can hold more data than just `Strings`. In fact, take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). You can see that Intents can hold `Longs`, `Doubles`, `Floats`, `Parcelables`, etc.

Comment: i am having another problem, for some reason my activity2 is not receiving the user input, when i display the int on activity2 its always the default value in "getIntExtra("foobar", 0);" so it just keeps reporting as 0

Comment: If you're using string literals as your key instead using a constant, then this could be attributed to a misspelling. For example, calling `getIntExtra("foosbar", 0);` would return 0 since there is no value keyed to "foosbar".

Comment: You can avoid this by declaring constants either in your main `Activity` or in a "Constants" class if they are used by multiple `Activities`.

Comment: I checked everything and its all spelled rite, im going to post up my new code on my original post maybe you could take a look at it for me?

Comment: Ah, I see. You're calling `getIntExtra("MESSAGE_HW", 0);` This means your key is actually "MESSAGE_HW" instead whatever MESSAGE_HW represents. You'll want to call either `getIntExtra(MESSAGE_HW, 0);` or `getIntExtra(PreviousActivity.MESSAGE_HW, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Pass data from one activity to another activity "String" value.useing intent

Activityone

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activityone.this,Activitytwo.class)
intent.putExtra("TYPE", type);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activitytwo

```
Intent intent =getIntent();
Receivevalue =intent.getExtras().getString("TYPE");
(OR)
Receivevalue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TYPE");
```

Pass data from one activity to another activity "Integer" value.useing intent

Activityone

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activityone.this,Activitytwo.class)
intent.putExtra("TYPE", type);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activitytwo

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
value = intent.getIntExtra("TYPE", 0);     
// Type = intent.getIntExtra(name, defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the conversion part within **try/catch** block, because your strings may not be convertible into integer values.

```
int HW, OTW, HPD;

try{
    HW = Integer.valueOf(message1);
    OTW = Integer.valueOf(message2);
    HPD = Integer.valueOf(message3);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    //do something else here
    //for e.g. initializing default values to your int variables
}
```

*Or more appropriately, pass the integer values in your sending part and receive them as it is.

Comment: When i try this method i get this error:
Syntax error on token "cat", catch expected

Comment: @user1552475 its catch. That was a typo

Comment: That works thank you! i am going to try some of the other suggestions though so it is a bit more appropriate.

Comment: anything which works fine is appropriate **:)**. Anyhow, for an alternate solution, try sending integer values rather than strings

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on the send side:

```
 String message1 = editText.getText().toString();   
 intent.putExtra("MESSAGE_1", message1);
 String message2 = editText1.getText().toString();
 intent.putExtra("MESSAGE_2", message2);
 String message3 = editText2.getText().toString();
 intent.putExtra("MESSAGE_3", message3);
```

Receive side:

```
  if (getIntent() != null) {
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String mess1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MESSAGE_1"); 
        String mess2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MESSAGE_2"); 
        String mess3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MESSAGE_3"); 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using following code

In Your Calling Activity

```
         Intent value = new Intent(YourCallingActivity.this,DestinationActivity.class);
         value.putExtra("integerone", integeronevalue);
         value.putExtra("integertwo", integertwovalue);
         value.putExtra("integerthree", integertwovalue);
         startActivity(value);
```

In Destination Activity

```
        int integerone = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("integerone");
        int integertwo = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("integertwo");
        int integerthree = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("integerthree");
```

Hope it helps